# Connect my flutter app with a printer using wifi

Tags: flutter, dart, wifi, printers

How to connect my flutter app with a printer trough WIFI?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Users here will help you fix your solution, but you have to have tried coming up with a solution yourself. No one will write the solution for you from scratch. Please check the question guidelines and improve your question accordingly: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should generate an image and the share with the printer using [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) plugin. There isn't an obvious way to do it, so you'll have to try =D